# Choosing random data from an array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote some code that works fine and uses a for statement to iterate over the array and display the eight results like I want it to.

```
$Address = $RPC2->getaddressesbyaccount($_SESSION['email']); 
$iteration_addresses = 0;

    foreach($Address as $Another) {
        $iteration_addresses++;
        echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
        if($iteration_addresses == 8) break;
    }
```

But it usually chooses the same 8 results, how can I have it choose random results each AJAX call?

Comment: Have u tried `rand()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: Is this what you looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **[shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)** your array before you pick up entries.

> This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array.

```
$Address = $RPC2->getaddressesbyaccount($_SESSION['email']); 
shuffle($Address); // Here
$iteration_addresses = 0;

    foreach($Address as $Another) {
        $iteration_addresses++;
        echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
        if($iteration_addresses == 8) break;
    }
```

**[Fiddle (taken from PHP.net)](http://codepad.org/eA5Y9Ua1)**

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks.  Also, I have another array of "transactions" if you will, and it's descending from oldest to newest when I want it newest to oldest, how can I flip it via timestamp?

  $Transactions = $RPC2->listtransactions($_SESSION['email']); 
   foreach($Transactions as $Transaction) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . date("F j, g:i A", $Transaction['timereceived']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $Transaction['address'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $Transaction['amount'] . '</td>';
   }

Comment: I did a sort() around the $Transactions var and it didn't change anything.

Comment: How can I order them by which timestamp is greatest?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get exactly 8 randoms variables by your *SQL QUERY* like this:-

```
SELECT column FROM table
WHERE email='Your_email'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 8
```

I think this is CI framework then implement your model function like this

```
function getaddressesbyaccount($email)
{
   $this->db->order_by('address', 'RANDOM');
   $this->db->limit(8);
   $this->db->where(array('email'=>$email));
   $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

Then you can use this functions in your ajax implementations. Thanks.